# Jquery check value from radio buttons only if checked otherwise set given value

Tags: jquery, ajax, radio-button

i'm trying to send some radio buttons from a form with ajax, the problem is that i can't get the buttons' values.
Everything would be much much easier if i could just use

```
data: $('form#my_form').serialize(),
```

The problem is that that doesn't send any values at all if the radio buttons are not checked and i need some kind of "not checked" value for some radio buttons groups in order to validate the form in php and reply with an error message.
That's why i was trying with:

```
if ($('input[name=radio_group]').prop('checked')==true) {
        var radio_value=$('input:radio[name=radio_group]').val();
        }
    else {var radio_value=0;}
```

and then just sending the single values.
But the function above doesn't work: it returns the value as "0" if no radio buttons are checked but it keeps returning "0" even if they're cheked, it only returns the right value if the first radio button is checked, otherwise it's always "0".

Any suggestions?
Also, is there a simpler way to achieve what i want? I'd only need .serialize() to send a null or whatever value if the radio buttons are not checked.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all the radio buttons have the same name. May be they are not same that is the reason it is working only for the first radio button when it is checked. You can try this after ensuring the name of all the radio buttons

```
var radio_value = ($('input:radio[name=radio_group]:checked').val() || 0);
```

Comment: Works great thanks.
The names were all the same even when i tried my script tho.
There must've been something wrong with my script.
Thanks again, i lost like 2 hours trying to figure it out before posting.

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you...

```
var radio_value = $('input:radio[name=radio_group]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Already tried that but it keeps giving me the 0 value, it only gives the right value for the first radio button.

Comment: @g0dl3ss: forget about your if statement, just my one line is all you need. If you always get 0 then are you sure you have your HTML correct? can you post the relevant part in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the validation in javascript instead of bouncing too and from a php script.  I'm a big fan of jQuery Validation plugin.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Thanks, but i need to pass the values to php anyway.
Also i'd prefer to validate server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try .is(':checked'), something like below should do the trick,

```
if ($('input[name=radio_group]').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: The first part of the script works, the problem is the second part, gathering the value from the buttons.

Comment: Tried it even if the chosen answer works but it doesn't work for me, don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

if ($('input:[name=radio_group]').prop('checked')==true)

{

```
 var radio_value = $('input:radio[name=radio_group]:checked').val();
```

}

else

{

```
var radio_value=0;
```

}